# How can I call this script from a button click

Tags: javascript, execution, src

I'd like the following script to execute as the result of a button click()

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/buzz/v1/activities/search?callback=handler&alt=json&q=ruby&max-results=100"></script>
```

All client side code; html & javascript.  I'm calling a javascript function on the button click and tried using document.write() to write out the above, but I can't get the script to execute.

Or, maybe the code is executing, but its not reaching the callback=handler.

I do almost all server side coding (asp.net) and I'm a little lost in the javascript/client side of things.

Comment: When that URL is accessed it will return a JSON object.  What do you want to do with that data?

Comment: yes..the URL contains the callback=handler element.  handler(response) parses the response.data.items.   All of this works fine if I just have the script tags embeded in the html.  I would like to be able to allow the user to enter a search term, pass the search term to a function, embed the search term in the src=URL.  my first hurdle is calling the script on demand, rather than every time the document loads.  does that make sens?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker it calls the callback with the JSON (in his case the callback is named `handler`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `handler` should be the name of a client-side function that will receive the data.  You should also add a click event handler to the button and use AJAX to retrieve the results.  Here's how you would do it using jQuery (which I recommend).  Note using jQuery you can pass the name of the handler as `?` and it will construct a handler for you using the anonymous function you supply.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() { // execute on document ready
       $('#ButtonID').click( function() { // add the click event handler to button
          $.getJSON( 'https://www.googleapis.com/buzz/v1/activities/search?callback=?&alt=json&q=ruby&max-results=100', function(result) {
                // do something with the result
          });
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: I have another page, the page I started with, and this works fine.  I have one <script> block in the body with the src="https:/.www.googleapis.com/ etc.... and another <script> block in the body that wraps the handler() function.  Done in that fashion, it works great.  i get a page filled with 100 entries, parsed and formatted by the handler() function.  I'm just trying to move the code to an event/user driven model.  I appreciate your post.  I've played with jQuery but this is still somewhat over my head, but a fun weekend learning experience.

Comment: wanted to let you know that I got the jQuery approach working.  I have implemented a text box that accepts a search term. On the button click, I concatenate the term into the call to the googleapis.com url and I get good results.  Writing to a <div> I clear the div conents, then write the results so each time I change the search term, I get the new results.  Basic, I know, but a lot of fun to learn.  Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
window.onload = function() {
   var btn = document.getElementById('id_of_your_button');
   btn.onclick = function() {
      var scr = document.createElement('script');
      scr.src = "https://www.googleapis.com/buzz/v1/activities/search?callback=handler&alt=json&q=ruby&max-results=100";
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr);
   };
};
```

Comment: How do you handle synchronization with this method?

Comment: thanks for the reply.  sorry to be a clod, but do I wrap that in <script></script> and place it in the <head>?